# postgresql + how to print all hosts

Tags: linux, postgresql, ambari, hdp

we have ambari cluster with postgresql

we try to print all hosts in the cluster as the following , but seems my select command not right

```
psql -U ambari ambari
Password for user ambari:
psql (9.2.24)
Type "help" for help.

ambari=>
ambari-> select host_id from hosts;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "select"
LINE 2: select host_id from hosts;
        ^
ambari=>
```

where I am wrong?

Comment: Try to only issue the query starting from `select ...`. Apparently you entered something before it, maybe some invisible characters yet not not classifying as ignorable white space. You didn't copy and paste the query from somewhere by any chance?

Comment: see my answer I found it

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.2 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the command is ( with details of mem )

```
ambari=>
select host_name, ipv4, public_host_name, total_mem from hosts;
```

or

```
ambari=> select host_name,  public_host_name  from hosts;
```